# C# Create MIME Message?

Tags: c#, mime, pkcs#7

Is there any built in functionality to MIME a file in C# .Net? What I am looking to do is:

1. Convert a file into a MIME message
2. Sign the MIME Message to a pcks 7 blob
3. MIME that pkcs 7 blob
4. Finally encrypt the entire thing.

Any suggestions on how I would go about this (not the encryption or signing part but the MIMEing)? What exactly is envolved in MIMEing a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good commercial package for a small fee:
[Mime4Net](http://www.mime4.net/)

Comment: If Petey accepts this answer, I'll award the bounty. My guess is that a commercial package won't be what is desired, but I cannot speak for Petey. Personally I would go this route to get something I felt confident would work.

Comment: "Small" IFF you don't want the source.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than deal with third party libraries, I suggest you look to the core .NET library. Use the [Attachment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment.aspx) class; it's been around since .NET 2.

Comment: Is it possible to extract the MIME encoded message from the System.Net.Mail classes without sending it?

Comment: @Rup: excellent point. The answer is, of course, no. At least, not without digging into the internal MailWriter class. I obviously misread the question; if he wanted to sign and encrypt a MIME attachment as part as an email, it's as easy as signing and encrypting the content before passing it to the Attachment.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no such support in the bare .NET. You have to try one of third party libraries. One of them is our [Rebex Secure Mail for .NET](http://www.rebex.net/secure-mail.net/). Following code shows how to achieve it:

```
using Rebex.Mail;
using Rebex.Mime.Headers;
using Rebex.Security.Certificates;
...

// load the sender's certificate and 
// associated private key from a file 
Certificate signer = Certificate.LoadPfx("hugo.pfx", "password");

// load the recipient's certificate 
Certificate recipient = Certificate.LoadDer("joe.cer");

// create an instance of MailMessage 
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

// set its properties to desired values 
message.From = "hugo@example.com";
message.To = "joe@example.com";
message.Subject = "This is a simple message";
message.BodyText = "Hello, Joe!";
message.BodyHtml = "Hello, <b>Joe</b>!";

// sign the message using Hugo's certificate 
message.Sign(signer);

// and encrypt it using Joe's certificate 
message.Encrypt(recipient);

// if you wanted Hugo to be able to read the message later as well, 
// you can encrypt it for Hugo as well instead - comment out the previous 
// encrypt and uncomment this one: 
// message.Encrypt(recipient, signer)
```

(Code taken from the [S/MIME tutorial page](http://www.rebex.net/secure-mail.net/tutorial-mail-secure.aspx#creating-encrypted-message))

Answer (score 0):

Something that hasn't been mentioned is [MimeKit](http://www.mimekit.net/).
It does everything that you need it to do.

(this is still a top hit in google so thought I'd add this gem)